How to change the default pagebuilder margin in Shopware 6?
By default a cms-element in the pagebuilder of Shopware 6 has a margin of 20px. I want this value to be zero, how can I change this?

Just to make it clear: I know I can simply change this value manually in the pagebuilder. But my question specifically is that when I add a new element on a page in the pagebuilder I want the margin to already be zero, so that I don't have to modify this manually for every element that I add to the page.
I can't find any documentation about this. But since this value is so specific and always 20px it must be stored somewhere.

There is an open-source plugin available for that. Compatible with 6.4/6.5/6.6: https://github.com/MelvinAchterhuis/MelvZeroMarginBlocks
Can be installed with composer:
composer require melvinachterhuis/zero-margin-blocks-shopware6-plugin

